# Determine twitter relationship via tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am looking a way to find out relationship between twitter users via tweepy
I am using `lookup_friendships()` to determine relationship but it always gives true. Here is my code:

```
import tweepy, time

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

user = api.get_user("LeCorrector");

rel = api.lookup_friendships(screen_names=user.screen_name)

for x in rel:
    print(isinstance(x, tweepy.models.Relationship))
```

`lookup_friendships` returns a list of `tweepy.models.Relationship objects` and when I print them I always get true.
My tweepy version is 2.1. I couldn't find any documentation for this function so I'm not sure that I'm using it right. Could anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing isinstance which checks the type and returns `True` or `False`. If you need object you need to print x:

something like:

```
if(isinstance(x, tweepy.models.Relationship)):
    print x
```

Comment: yes, you'r right, but that didn't help much. now it is printing <tweepy.models.Relationship object at 0x01E1CCF0>
<tweepy.models.Relationship object at 0x01E1CDB0>
<tweepy.models.Relationship object at 0x01E1CD30>
<tweepy.models.Relationship object at 0x01E1CD90>
<tweepy.models.Relationship object at 0x01E1CCD0>
<tweepy.models.Relationship object at 0x01E1CD50>

Comment: Well , I have not dwelved into tweepy but basically you need to access what attribute of `x` you need. you are basicaly printing objects. Something like `x.screen_name` may be. See what attribute are available with `print dir(x)`